# Проблема при установке Oracle JDK на Debian

Tags: debian, java

Возникла ошибка при установке *Oracle JDK* на *Debian 8 Jessie*:

```
rostislav@Rostislav-PC:~/Загрузки$ sudo dpkg -i jdk1.8.0-91_1.8.091-1_amd64.deb
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета jdk1.8.0-91.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 119167 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке jdk1.8.0-91_1.8.091-1_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается jdk1.8.0-91 (1.8.091-1) …
Настраивается пакет jdk1.8.0-91 (1.8.091-1) …
Unpacking JAR files...
    tools.jar...
    plugin.jar...
    javaws.jar...
    deploy.jar...
    rt.jar...
    jsse.jar...
    charsets.jar...
    localedata.jar...
    jfxrt.jar...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-91.postinst: line 641: /usr/sbin/alternatives: Нет такого файла или каталога
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-91.postinst: line 653: /usr/sbin/alternatives: Нет такого файла или каталога
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета jdk1.8.0-91 (--install):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 127
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 jdk1.8.0-91
```

Процесс установки был таким (инструкцию нашел [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/143113/)):

1. Скачал официальную версию JDK с сайта Oracle.
2. Установил *alien* из официального репозитория.
3. Перегнал .rpm в .deb командой `sudo alien --scripts
   jdk-8u91-linux-x64.rpm`
4. Установил .deb пакет командой `sudo dpkg -i
   jdk1.8.0-91_1.8.091-1_amd64.deb`, во время чего и возникла ошибка

Из-за чего произошла ошибка и как ее исправить?

---

**UPD_0 (kvm):** При попытке удалить JDK:

```
rostislav@Rostislav-PC:~$ dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq jdk1.8.0-91
dpkg: ошибка: запрошенная операция требует привилегий суперпользователя
rostislav@Rostislav-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq jdk1.8.0-91
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 116630 файлов и каталогов.)
Удаляется jdk1.8.0-91 (1.8.091-1) …
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-91.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: Нет такого файла или каталога
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-91.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: Нет такого файла или каталога
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета jdk1.8.0-91 (--remove):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-removal возвратил код ошибки 127
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 jdk1.8.0-91
rostislav@Rostislav-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq jdk1.8.0-91(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 116630 файлов и каталогов.)
Удаляется jdk1.8.0-91 (1.8.091-1) …
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-91.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: Нет такого файла или каталога
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-91.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: Нет такого файла или каталога
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета jdk1.8.0-91 (--purge):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-removal возвратил код ошибки 127
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 jdk1.8.0-91
```

Comment: Попробуйте установить из подключаемого репозитория https://rtfm.co.ua/debian-ustanovka-oracle-java-8-iz-repozitoriya/

Comment: `/usr/sbin/alternatives: Нет такого файла или каталога` Краем уха слышал, что этот каталог есть на системах, родственных redhat, на который прежде всего и ориентирован oracle java. Надо использовать oracle linux, red hat, может быть fedora, cent os.

Comment: @Sergey учитывая то, что пакет перегнан из RPM, этот исход ожидаем :)

Comment: @D-side теоретически, если поколдовать над postinst/postrm, то может заработать. Как минимум, надо заменить `/usr/sbin/alternatives` на `/usr/sbin/update-alternatives`, но что-то мне подсказывает, то этого будет не достаточно =)

Comment: @kmv ...только это нафиг не нужно, когда можно сделать проще, что вы и описали :)

Comment: Интересно что делать будите, когда не только рпм, а ещё и ядро и системные библиотеки не той системы окажутся?

Comment: @Sergey, матерится и бить по клавиатуре. Что же еще? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установить JDK из rpm это целое приключение, лучше воспользоваться [java-package](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage).

- Убедитесь, что подключены contrib архивы в `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

  ```
  deb <url> jessie main contrib non-free
  ```
- Установите java-package: `apt install java-package`.
- Скачайте JDK с сайта Oracle, но не rpm, а tar.gz.
- Запустите создание deb-пакета JDK:

  ```
  fakeroot make-jpkg jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz
  ```

  Возможно, появятся ошибки о неудовлетворенных зависимостях, установите пакеты, о которых говорится в ошибках, затем заново запустите создание пакета. В моем случае было:

  ```
  sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx libxslt1.1 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1
  ```
- Удалите старый некорректно установленный пакет JDK.
- Установите созданный пакет

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i oracle-java8-jdk_8u91_amd64.deb
  ```

---

**UPD1**. Если снести кривой пакет JDK через `apt remove jdk1.8.0-91` не удается, удаляем его принудительно:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq jdk1.8.0-91
sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq jdk1.8.0-91
```

---

**UPD2**. Создайте симлинк

```
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/alternatives
```

и еще раз попробуйте снести. Потом удалите симлинк.

Comment: О, как раз хотел вопрос из-за этой ошибки обновлять. Но даже с новым способом JDK не сносится :(.

Comment: Я добавил ошибку в вопрос, но пойду пороюсь в гугле, может что-то и найду.

Comment: @bukashka101 попробуйте с трюк с симлинком

Comment: О! Симлинк помог (заодно потом почитаю, что это :)). Продолжаю установку.

Comment: УХУ! УСТАНОВИЛОСЬ! :D если не секрет, где Вы нашли\узнали этот способ установки JDK?

Comment: @bukashka101 Честно, не вспомню уже =) Когда-то давно тоже сталкивался с задачей пакет с jdk под дебиан собрать, тогда и нашел javapackage. Плюс сегодня проверил, что с jdk8 способ работает.